# Comprehensive online manual for LaTeX2e user macros and environments

Tags: macros, documentation

I find myself sometimes in the position that I need to know the "official" syntax and behavior of LaTeX2e user macros or environments. I'm talking about common things like `minipage`.
Usually I find *something* by doing a Google search for `latex <command>`, e.g. `latex minipage`. There are a couple of online helps in English and German available, but there are mostly incomplete. To stick with the example of `minipage`, most of them do not include the second and third optional argument.

**Is there a comprehensive online or PDF manual freely available which explains the full syntax of LaTeX2e user level macros/environments?**

Wanted features would be:

- Comprehensive (all arguments, all macros/environments, default values for optional arguments)
- Well organized, so that all macros/environments are quickly found.
- Nicely formatted

I had a look at the [LaTeX wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) and other online sites, as well as `source2e`, but none of them really fulfill the above points. I realize that there might be books which handle these but I'm looking for something digital.

I personally need this because I like to support or emulate such standard macros or environments in my packages, but normal user will find a comprehensive manual also useful.

If there is no such document I'm might add it to my TODO list.

Comment: The 'free' is I guess the issue. You can buy the _Guide to LaTeX_ and _The LaTeX Companion_ as PDF books, but have to pay.

Comment: @JosephWright: Good point. Note that I'm looking more for a technical reference, not a guide.

Comment: I assume you mean something like _TeX by Topic_ in terms of formal specifications?

Comment: @JosephWright: I mean, no introduction or long explanation required, but the arguments and behavior explained.

Comment: There isn't, as far as I know.

Comment: When I taught LaTeX, I made a [list of LaTeX commands](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~goutet/latex/liste_commandes.pdf) for my students with the most common commands, but it's in French, doesn't include all commands and there are commands coming from some common packages.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like the (unofficial) »[LaTeX2e Reference Manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/latex2e-help-texinfo)«. Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: Actually, this looks very promising. I might have seen this already once, but forgot that it existed.

Comment: And users may contribute for improving and extending: http://home.gna.org/latexrefman/

Comment: Yes, this is not comprehensive, but useful enough for most users.

Comment: `texdoc latex2e` is the command line shortcut for this manual

Answer (score 10):

AFAIK, there isn't such a document. Even the book *Guide to LaTeX*, or the Appendix H of the book as a reference, is not comprehensive. When I wrote my book on LaTeX, I find that I have to read `source2e` sometimes.

It is difficult to say, what are user macros in LaTeX2e. I think all macros (and some primitives also) in LaTeX2e kernel and standard documents, without a `@` in the name, are user-level. For convinience, `graphics` and some other common packages can be added into the list.

Some examples you can find in `source2e`:

- Is `\DeclareMathVersion` a user-level macro? It is described in `fntguide` but I think almost all users and most package writers would never use it.
- What about `\ooalign`? It is come from Plain TeX and is mainly used for compound symbols.
- And how do you think about the symbol `\relbar`? You can find it in the definition of `\longrightarrow`, but why should I use it myself?

As Thorsten Donig said, the document `latex2e-help-texinfo` is a good refernece. There are some similar ones:

- [`latex2e-help-texinfo`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/latex2e-help-texinfo): *LaTeX: Structured documents for TeX --- unofficial LaTeX reference manual*.

  It is distributed with MiKTeX and TeX Live. A good reference for common users.
- [`tex-references`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/tex-references): *References for TeX and Friends*.

  Available on CTAN. A HTML reference for Plain TeX, LaTeX, and some others. Very useful.
- `LatexHelpBook`: [LaTeX Help e-Book](http://vm.cs.msu.ru/sotr/VabMGU/latex.htm) in HTML and CHM format.

  Available [on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/LatexHelpBook). Also distributed with WinEdt editor.

  It is a collection of `latex2e-help-info`, `usrguide`, `clsguide`, `fntguide`, `cfgguide`, `modguide`, UK-FAQ, The TeX Catalogue, ... Quite a lot of documents in one file, but badly selected. Personally I don't like it.

maybe more...

Answer (score 4):

I've always found [Help on LaTeX Commands](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-2.html) to be useful as a quick reference. Of course it's all `html` based, so it doesn't meet your criterion of being a nicely formatted PDF.  But I'll leave the answer up for others who might not have such requirements.

Comment: Thanks, that was one of the online sources I mentioned in my question. It is not bad, but not complete. For example not all possible arguments of `minipage` are explained: http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-267.html