# Documentation of LaTeX2e source

Tags: documentation, latex-base

**Where are the best places to look if one would like to understand the LaTeX2e *source code*?**

Related:

- [Comprehensive online manual for LaTeX2e user macros and environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34342/14996)
- [Are there guidelines on how to read commented sources of LaTeX packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3043/14996)

Comment: `texdoc source2e`

Comment: Did you read the source code (`.dtx` files)?

Comment: @JosephWright Oops :-) I've only ever stared at the docstrip-generated `latex.ltx` and have thus been wondering where all this community knowledge comes from. I think the reason why I didn't know is that whenever someone pasted snippets from the LaTeX source (in answers on this site), I've searched them, and was led to something like `latex.ltx`, which is of course unannotated. So I simply didn't look in the right place or didn't follow pointers far enough. The header of `latex.ltx` does mention `docstrip`, but I didn't know that `dtx` was a format for annotated sources. Thanks!

Comment: @LoverofStructure one useful tip if you _are_ looking at latex.ltx and decide to switch to the documented form, search backwards for `%%%` and it which tell you which documented file the bit you are looking at came from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As indicated in the comments the source is all written in `dtx` source form and can be typeset with a fully indexed cross referenced documented form documenting every command and indexing the use of every command in the source. You can process the sources yourself with latex and makeindex but most distributions have a `source2e.pdf` ready made.

Comment: Oops :-) See my comment above.

Comment: @LoverofStructure Personally I _always_ use latex.ltx (which is usually to hand in my emacs) rather than source2e, but then I made source2e I don't want to have to read it as well:-)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: there's no hope of clarifying your own docs (apart from the odd typo).  you need a user to point out the problems.  `source2e` is, of course, too bulky to use as a quick reference, so if you know the stuff, it's reasonable to read the source.  (i do, and i don't know latex half as well as david or you...)